# Differential Equation by Laplace Transform

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform

[image]

[image]

I was solving normal IVP problmes but I have no idea as how to solve this problem with $u(t)$ present in the question. Please help with this one.

Comment: Are you using the unilateral Laplace transform (that is, the integration is over $t \ge 0$)? If so, you can see that $u(t) = 1$ for all $t$ of interest.